# Is there a means by which a browser can be triggered to 'rescue' the DOM, after the initial page-load?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've come to realise, recently, that while a browser will attempt to "rescue" the DOM during its initial construction from invalid, or otherwise broken, HTML it doesn't appear to respect valid HTML rules after that initial construction.

As an example:

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

img,
td > img {
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
}

tr>img {
  border-color: red;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <!-- this was deliberately inserted into a bad
          place (I already know it's wrong) -->
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png" />
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bhLz9crq/1/).

In my current crop of browsers, Chrome 56, Opera 43, Edge 38, Firefox Developer Edition 53 and Internet Explorer 11, I see the following as expected, the `<img>` has been removed from the `<table>` element because it's invalid for the `<img>` element in a `<table>` can be a child of only the `<th>` or `<td>` elements:

[image]

This is as expected and what I had assumed until relatively recently, would be consistent behaviour, preventing us from, intentionally or otherwise, abusing JavaScript  to create an invalid DOM.

To demonstrate JavaScript's apparent willingness to create an invalid DOM we have the following, on page-load the first `<img>` is removed from the `<table>` (as above, and as expected); though clicking the `<button>` will insert an `<img>` element as the next-sibling of the selected `<td>` element:

```js
//
//
let image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png'
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let cell = document.querySelector('td:first-child');
  cell.parentNode.insertBefore(image.cloneNode(), cell.nextSibling);
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

img,
td > img {
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
}

tr > img {
  border-color: red;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button>add image inside a &lt;tr&gt; element (<strong>bad!</strong>)</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png" />
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bhLz9crq/).

Clicking the `<button>`, again on all my current browsers (as above), gives the following:

[image]

As noted, the above is certainly invalid HTML, as the `<img>` is a direct descendant of the `<tr>`, selected by the CSS rule of `tr > img` to apply a red border.

So: is there a non-destructive (doesn't destroy bound event-handlers) means by which we might force the browser to repeat whatever means of 'rescue' is implemented on page-load, to move the inserted `<img>` to an appropriately 'valid' place?

In closing, I'd prefer any solutions – should a solution be possible – to be posted in the native DOM API, rather than a JavaScript library. By all means post an answer showing how much easier it might be with a library, but only *along with* a native DOM API solution.

Also, as a further addenda, I don't want to *emulate* the native DOM's 'rescue' – it seems there would be far too many edge-cases to accommodate with such an approach – but simply trigger that 'rescue'.

Comment: I hereby extend my apology for, first, a wall of text and, second, the lack of any freehand red circles (although pretty red borders are offered as a substitute for those of us visiting from [meta]).

Comment: The reason error recovery only kicks in during page load is because it only takes place when parsing markup - DOM manipulations don't involve markup at all, since it's *elements* that are being manipulated, not their textual representations. So, I'd imagine, triggering this error recovery requires reparsing the element tree in its serialized form (markup).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a use case here for this or are you just asking for general knowledge?

Comment: @Dimitris: pure general knowledge, to answer a question I was surprised had no pre-existing answer; the answer may lead to use-cases, though, such as preventing users unfamiliar with HTML validity (accidentally or otherwise) using JavaScript utilities to create broken HTML.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks for the clarification, I was working my way towards figuring that out after I realised that, after reading [Ibrahim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42537750/82548), re-writing the `innerHTML` of the containing element worked; though your explanation was far more concise than my fragmented thought processes :)

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that the parsing process does not "rescue" the DOM. The resulting DOM may well still be very invalid, and it's not the purpose of the parsing rules to attempt to make it valid. Instead, the purpose of parsing rules is essentially to handle the markup in a backward compatible way, so that modern browsers treat broken markup the same way that they have always done. The idea is that users expect the pages that they visit to work, so they must continue to work in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the `innerHTML` kind of mimics the loading of the page. By reseting the `innerHTML` you force the browser to do the same job it did when loading on a particular element.

Here in the function `fix`, we took the `innerHTML` of the element and put it back and the browser will automatically fix the errors that it would fix on load.

```js
//
//
let image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png'
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let cell = document.querySelector('td:first-child');
  cell.parentNode.insertBefore(image.cloneNode(), cell.nextSibling);
});

function fix(selector) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

img,
td > img {
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
}

tr > img {
  border-color: red;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button>add image inside a &lt;tr&gt; element (<strong>bad!</strong>)</button>
<button onclick="fix('table')">Fix it Felix!</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png" />
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/92t7rs.png" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered that approach; the one problem I can see with this method, though, is that resetting the `innerHTML` of an element destroys any event-handlers bound to those pre-existing elements. I've just updated the question to clarify that I'm looking for a 'non-destructive' approach.

Comment: That is the disadvantage of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Indeed, and it may well be the only means to achieve (most of) the end-result.